# How would I put text over an image in HTML email code?

Tags: html, email, debugging

I've tried everything under the sun to make some text appear on the image with my current HTML code but to no avail.

No matter what I do, the text always appears on the bottom of the entire page and never on the image.

I've looked at so many posts on SO but they just don't work for me.

Below is one of my many attempts in terms of fixing this issue and moving on.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my HTML code:

```html
 <body width="100%" bgcolor="#f4f8f1">
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="width-320" style="margin: 0 auto;" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="width-320 header-welcome" width="600">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img class="hide" style="display: block;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png" alt="some text" width="1200" height="1000" border="0" />
                                            <p>This is always appearing on the bottom of the page!</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0` in the style tag of `img` element?

Comment: @sanketd617 yeah, it just shifts my whole image to the left

Comment: Then to the parent element of `img` tag i.e. `a` tag in your case, add `position: relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` and `left:0` `right:0` also use `z-index` to show the text above the image
Hope this helps !

```html
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#f4f8f1">
  <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="width-320" style="margin: 0 auto;" width="600">
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="width-320 header-welcome" width="600">
                          <img class="hide" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-1;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png" alt="some text" width="1200" height="1000" border="0" />
                          <p>This is always appearing on the bottom of the page!</p>
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the image from your css

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="bg-img">
    <p>This is always appearing on the bottom of the page!</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Comment: Okay, thank you for your information. Im still newbie here and try to helping people :)

Answer (score 0):

_ Check if file image is really linked after send email. 
_ Define a -> style='display:block;'
_ Maybe you can try: in a: style='display:block; width:x; height:x; background: url('link_image') no-repeat 0 0;'

Comment: Does not work with Outlook Desktop version (background images are not supported)

Answer (score 0):

For an email, you need the following:

```
<tr>
    <td class="width-320 header-welcome" width="600" background="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png">
        <p>
            <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff;">This is always appearing on the bottom of the page!</a>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You'll also need to ensure you generate coding here as well so that the background image appears in Outlook - https://backgrounds.cm/.

In an ideal world you would add valign="middle" to your table cell to ensure the text sits in the middle, however that doesn't work in Outlook either. I'd advise adding table rows with set heights so you can space your content appropriately.